# Cannot Call __construct() Variables In PHP By Their Names

Tags: php

I have really started to look at PHP Classes, and I can not understand why this does not work. I thought if you define a variable in the constructor you can call it by that variable name. That is not the case though(?), let me give you all an example:

```
class test {

    public function __construct($item) {

        $this->item= $anItem;

    }

    public function callvar() {

        //Does not work
        return $anItem;

    }

    public function callvar() {

        //Works
        return $this->item;

    }

}
```

So my question is, am I doing something wrong? Or must you call a `__construct` variable by `$this->item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$anItem** is local variable in construct function, so it isn't a variable for another method. But **$this->item** is property of **test class** so that every method in **test class** can access this property as a global variable

Comment: Hmm, so there is no other to access a `__contruct()` variables other than with `$this->item`?

Comment: Personally, I always assign class properties in __contruct() function. Ex: __contruct($p1, $p2) for $this->p1, $this->p2. Then others use $this->p1, $this->p2. __contruct() is only a method

Comment: Hmm, that is what I have been doing. I was just wondering if there is a way to shorten it down :) Thank You